# Compose two Transform streams in Node.js

Tags: node.js, stream, gulp

I have a no-op Transform stream test that outputs the list of all files passed through it. Why does the following code outputs the list of files only once? How do I compose two streams properly?

```
var composed = test().pipe(test());
gulp.src('source/*').pipe(composed);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compose streams, you `pipe()` the first to the second, but you also have to modify `pipe()` and `unpipe()` so they apply to the second stream.  This way additional calls to `pipe()` on the composed stream will use the output of the second stream instead of the first.

```
function compose(s1, s2) {
    s1.pipe(s2);
    s1.pipe = function (dest) {
        return s2.pipe(dest);
    }
    s1.unpipe = function (dest) {
        return s2.unpipe(dest);
    }
    return s1;
}

var composed = compose(test(), test());
gulp.src('source/*')
    .pipe( composed )  // src -> s1 -> s2
    .pipe( ... );      // s2 -> ...
```

Comment: That's what I eventually did. The problem is that result of such `compose` operation is inconsistent: it has `pipe` of second stream, but events and properties of first. The cleaner approach would be to create a new stream class from scratch, but there's a wide variety of stream types, and the resulting stream could be `Readable`, `Writable` of `Transform` depending on types of passed streams. I haven't found a way to check for stream types to make this possible.

Comment: Yes. You could also overwrite the returned s1's `on()` method to link to `s2` for event, but that *still* doesn't give properties. The complete solution would be a to implement a full new stream.

Comment: As answered here: [how-to-compose-transform-streams-in-node-js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697831/how-to-compose-transform-streams-in-node-js) one can use the module [multipipe](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multipipe) to compose streams.

Answer (score 1):

`pipe()` returns the stream being piped **to**, not **from** (to allow chaining). So the second line is basically trying to pipe to the second instance of `test()`. What you need to do instead is:

```
var first = test();
first.pipe(test());
gulp.src('source/*').pipe(first);
```

Or:

```
gulp.src('source/*')
    .pipe(test())
    .pipe(test());
```

Comment: Awesome. I don't have an idea why I couldn't figure this out myself.

Comment: (The second is not an option for me, as it isn't a composed stream. Though you should do it this way in most cases.)