# How to compose transform Streams in node.js

Tags: node.js, stream

I have a csv parser implemented as a series of transform streams:

```
process.stdin
    .pipe(iconv.decodeStream('win1252'))
    .pipe(csv.parse())
    .pipe(buildObject())
    .pipe(process.stdout);
```

I'd like to abstract the parser (in its own module) and be able to do:

```
process.stdin.
    .pipe(parser)
    .pipe(process.stdout);
```

where `parser` is just the composition of the previously used transform streams.

If I do

```
var parser = iconv.decodeStream('win1252')
    .pipe(csv.parse())
    .pipe(buildObject());
```

then `parser` is set to the buildObject() stream and only this transformation stream receives the data.

If I do

```
var parser = iconv.decodeStream('win1252');
parser
    .pipe(csv.parse())
    .pipe(buildObject());
```

it doesn't work either, as `.pipe(process.stdout)` will be called on the 1st transform stream and the 2 others will be bypassed.

Any recommendation for an elegant composition of streams?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in way to do that, but there is cool [multipipe](https://github.com/segmentio/multipipe) package. 
Use like this:

```
var multipipe = require('multipipe');

var parser = multipipe(iconv.decodeStream('win1252'), csv.parse(), buildObject());
```

Comment: Same. This is brilliant. Also, multipipe's source code is very short, so worth checking out the implementation for anyone who values a look under the hood.

Comment: There is also [`pumpify`](https://github.com/mafintosh/pumpify) which similarly allows you to compose multiple streams.

Answer (score 5):

As of 2022, and nodejs v16, there is a new `compose` function in the stream module, that build a Duplex stream from a list of streams.

see : https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamcomposestreams

works with `.pipe()` and async syntax.

Answer (score 4):

I've been struggling with this issue (and some others!). I found [highlandjs](https://caolan.github.io/highland/) solved nearly all my problems. In this case their [pipeline](https://caolan.github.io/highland/#pipeline) command did the trick:

```
var h = require('highland');
var parser = h.pipeline(iconv.decodeStream('win1252'), csv.parse(), buildObject());
```

Comment: I would've sold my first child for this answer. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be done natively now.

```js
const { PassThrough, Transform } = require('stream');

const compose = (...streams) => {
  const first = new PassThrough();
  const last = new PassThrough();
  const result = new Transform();

  [first, ...streams, last].reduce(
    (chain, stream) => (
      stream.on('error', (error) => result.emit('error', error)),
      chain.pipe(stream)
    ),
  );

  result._transform = (chunk, enc, cb) => {
    last.once('data', (chunk) => cb(null, chunk));
    first.push(chunk, enc);
  };

  result._flush = (cb) => {
    last.once('end', () => cb(null));
    first.push(null);
  };

  return result;
};
```